# how to order a field based on two parts of the row value

Tags: order-by

I have a field with contents of the form 
22/4,
30/8,
30/5,
30/3

I want it ordered in the form 
22/4,
30/3,
30/5,
30/8

with the part after / ordered if the part before / is same!

Please help!!

Comment: What DBMS. Why isn't this two separate columns?

Comment: Its an entry by the user which is to be used as a whole later.. i have tried ordering the first part using substring_index, but unable to order the second part corresponding to the first

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Given the sample data you provided, and if this was stored as a varchar, the data should sort out as desired easily. I assume the first part is not always two digits? (Also assuming that you've got a column with these value sin different rows; if they're all in a single row, it's a different issue)

Answer (score 1):

A way to order such string is

**Step1: Create Split Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit]
(
@List VARCHAR(8000),
@Delimiter CHAR(1) = ','
)
RETURNS @Temp1 TABLE
(
ItemId INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY,
Item VARCHAR(8000) NULL
)
AS BEGIN

DECLARE @item VARCHAR(4000),
@iPos INT

SET @Delimiter = ISNULL(@Delimiter, ',')
SET @List = RTRIM(LTRIM(@List))

-- check for final delimiter
IF RIGHT(@List, 1) <> @Delimiter 
-- append final delimiter
SELECT @List = @List + @Delimiter

-- get position of first element
SELECT @iPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List, 1)

WHILE @iPos > 0
BEGIN
-- get item
SELECT @item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, 1, @iPos - 1)))
IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BREAK
-- remove item form list
SELECT @List = SUBSTRING(@List, @iPos + 1, LEN(@List) - @iPos + 1)
IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BREAK
-- insert item
INSERT @Temp1
VALUES ( @item )
IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BREAK
-- get position pf next item
SELECT @iPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List, 1)
IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BREAK
END
RETURN
END

GO
```

**Step2: split the string into tokens**

```
create table #string
(
field varchar(500)
)

insert into #string
select '22/4, 30/3, 30/5, 30/8,40/9,40/3'

----------------Order by string Tokens returned by function
select * 
from #string cross apply dbo.[fnSplit](field,',') atn
order by ltrim(rtrim(atn.Item ))

drop table #string
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply include the column which holds these values into an `order by` clause they will come out in the sequence you want.  For example

```
select
    ThisColumn
from MyTable
order by ThisColumn
```

This will work if your values genuinely are all form shown i.e. two digits, a slash and one digit.  If you have other formats the more involved solutions will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

First you find the position of your separating character ( / ). Then you order your table by left side of separator and right side of separator.

```
SELECT field
   ,CHARINDEX('/', field) as [Position of /]
   ,LEFT(field, CHARINDEX('/', field)-1) as Left_Sort
   ,RIGHT(field, LEN(field) - CHARINDEX('/', field)) as Right_Sort 
from #string 
order by 
   LEFT(field, CHARINDEX('/', field)-1)
   ,RIGHT(field, LEN(field) - CHARINDEX('/', field))
```

[image]